# Are classes depends on database tables?

Tags: database, class, dao, dto

I'm newbie to designing class diagrams.
As my application works as REST API, I would like to use DTO-DAO design patterns. For user registration module, DB contains 3 tables for user signon, profile and address.

Do I need to create 3 DTOs and corresponding DAOs to insert/update user signon, profile and address?
If so, what if I only one table is created instead of three tables and dropped two tables in future?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever design pattern you follow, data modelling is entirely upto you.Your design pattern should be based on your data modelling and your need. Not that,your data model will depend on the design pattern but on your need

Answer (score 1):

You can create whatever dto objects you like. However both your database design and your dto design is driven by the concepts in your system (user/company/address etc) this often called the domain.

You'll often find that the two are very similar, after all they both represent the same domain!

As to whether you need different dtos for different calls that really depends on you. Do you need a different class to represent an insert/update call? What's the difference? Often the update has an id (whereas the insert hasn't had one assigned yet). So why not have two where the update inherits from the insert but adds the id property?

Delete dtos, you can do these as either an update or just as an id. After all why bother to populate an entire object you're about tot delete. Personally I'd just say

```
DeleteUser(int id);
```

Much easier!

Comment: Thanks. I will create 3 DTOs for 3 tables, what if I only one table is created instead of three tables and dropped two tables in future?

Comment: @satyanarayana if you change your database you'll no doubt need to change your code. If this has answered your question please accept it